# Removing all occurrences of a letter and replacing with a count of how many errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I've got a code that in theory should take an input of DNA that has errors in it and removes all errors (N in my case) and places a count of how many N's were removing in that location.

My code:

```
class dnaString (str):
    def __new__(self,s):
        #the inputted DNA sequence is converted as a string in all upper cases
        return str.__new__(self,s.upper())      
    def getN (self):
        #returns the count of value of N in the sequence
        return self.count("N")
    def remove(self):

        print(self.replace("N", "{}".format(coolString.getN())))
#asks the user to input a DNA sequence
dna = input("Enter a dna sequence: ")
#takes the inputted DNA sequence, ???
coolString = dnaString(dna)
coolString.remove()
```

When I input `AaNNNNNNGTC` I should get `AA{6}GTC` as the answer, but when I run my code it prints out `AA666666GTC` because I ended up replacing every error with the count. How do I go about just inputting the count once?

Comment: One problem is that `return print()` returns `None`, which is what is called when you call `coolString.remove()`.

Comment: What exactly, do you except the line `return print()` to do?

Comment: Oops sorry I had copied and pasted an earlier verison. I edited the original code with what I have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to complete the task without external libraries, you can do it with the following:

```
def fix_dna(dna_str):
    fixed_str = ''
    n_count = 0
    n_found = False
    for i in range(len(dna_str)):
         if dna_str[i].upper() == 'N':
             if not n_found:
                 n_found = True
             n_count += 1
         elif n_found:
             fixed_str += '{' + str(n_count) + '}' + dna_str[i]
             n_found = False
             n_count = 0
         elif not n_found:
             fixed_str += dna_str[i]
    return fixed_str
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution, but does the job

```
from itertools import accumulate
s = "AaNNNNNNGTC"
for i in reversed(list(enumerate(accumulate('N'*100, add)))):
    s=s.replace(i[1], '{'+str(i[0] + 1)+'}')
s = 'Aa{6}GTC'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's expected, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

> Return a copy of string s **with all occurrences** of substring old replaced by new.

One solution could be using regexes. The [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) can take a callable that generates the replacement string:

```
import re

def replace_with_count(x):
    return "{%d}" % len(x.group())

test = 'AaNNNNNNGTNNC'

print re.sub('N+', replace_with_count, test)
```